# Difference between using count or !=nil on array to verify if empty?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to verify that an array is not empty and am just wondering if there is any difference between writing

```
if([myArray count])
```

and

```
if(myArray !=nil)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I just tried it with count as I had seen that before and that worked without throwing up any errors. I didnt actually try it with nil but I will later when I get back to the project. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, sort of, I really love how count can be used in this way, as in not only can it be used to return the number of objects in an array, in the most obvious sense, but it can also be called upon to make a check on an array to see if it is empty or not in cases where you need to check for that. That is pretty cool.

Comment: @shinnyWhack that's because in C (and related languages), the value `0` evaluates to `false`. This isn't true in all languages (for example, in Ruby `0` is `true`). As a total aside, in Rails there is a method `blank?`, which checks if the target is either `nil`, or if it's an array, if its `count` is 0. It's really nice to use :)

Comment: Thanks again, you have been really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would be different, although only in certain cases. For example, `NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` would not be `nil`, but its count would be 0.

Comment: So, given the array has been allocated and initialised, it will always at least be empty, therefore count 0. If it hadn't been allocated and initialised then it would be nil. Is that correct? So to check if empty array, count is preferable?

Answer (score 1):

The diff is you cannot use `!= nil` to check if array is empty. `count` returns number of elements in array. The pointer itself does not indicate that.